# Why did Jenkins forget about my job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

For posterity:

One of my [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) jobs disappeared after I upgraded some plugins.

I looked through the error log, and found that the [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) was failing while parsing the job config.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the [Promoted Builds Plugin release 2.9](https://github.com/jenkinsci/promoted-builds-plugin/tree/promoted-builds-2.9) broke in my scenario, which specified a promotion action to build a parameterized job.  I removed the section of the job conf file pertaining to promoted builds, restarted Jenkins, and the job reappeared.  Then I reconfigured the promotion action, and all seems fine.